# SpyOn express route handler function in controller

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

So i have a simple express route which I am trying to test using Jest. Below are the code snippets

`auth.route.ts`

```
import * as authController from '../controllers/auth.controller';

const router = express.Router();

// POST /api/user/register
router.post(`${userApis.register}`, authController.register);
export { router };
```

`auth.route.test.ts`

```
it('register', async() => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(authController, "register");
  await request(app).post('/api/user/register');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the test fails. Below is the error.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

One way i got it working is re writing my route as below but that is not the right way i think

```
import * as authController from '../controllers/auth.controller';

const router = express.Router();

// POST /api/user/register
router.post(`${userApis.register}`, (req, res, next) => {
  authController.register(req, res, next);
});
export { router };
```

What would be solution for this. I am new to Jest.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` import object is read-only by specs and can fail to be spied or mocked depending on a specific setup.

```
router.post(`${userApis.register}`, authController.register)
```

line is evaluated on import, `jest.spyOn` in test scope is evaluated later and cannot affect it.

In case an import should be only spied and not mocked, this can be done for all tests in a module mock:

```
import * as authController from '../controllers/auth.controller';

jest.mock('../controllers/auth.controller', () => {
  const controller = jest.requireActual('../controllers/auth.controller');
  jest.spyOn(controller, "register");
  return controller
});
```

That `register` call is asserted doesn't have a lot of value, asserting a response that is expected from this route handler would be enough. A request most likely causes side effects (database queries), they can be mocked or asserted instead.

Comment: can you point to any article / post where i could read about it please?

if * import is the problem, would it help if i import functions separately?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What happens in your case is basically `router.post(authController.register); ... jest.spyOn(authController, "register")`. It's evaluated in this order. You can't spy on a function that has already been passed as a callback. router.post will use original authController.register function, no matter what you do with it later. I cannot suggest any specific reading, it's just how things work in JS. A common way to test Express are integration tests with https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest